# How to filter a list into 2 separate list

Tags: c#, list, filter

I am pulling a users active directory groups into a list.  There are several groups in the list, some of which are listed as

Board Testing &
Board Testing Admin

I filtered the list into a new list that contained just everything that started with "Board" so now my list contains only the 2 lines above.

However now I need 2 separate list.  So from the original long list of groups, I need to create a list that only contains the line "Board Testing".  And another list that only contains "Board Testing Admin".

What I did originally will now not work.

```
    List<string> GroupNames = new List<string>();
    GroupNames.AddRange(ADConnect.ADConnect.GetGroups(adusername));
    List<string> FilteredGroup = new List<string>();
    var FilteredName = new String[] { "Board" };
    var names = GroupNames.Where(t => FilteredName.Any(c => t.Contains(c)));
    FilteredGroup.AddRange(names);
    cmbgroup.DataSource = FilteredGroup;
```

Comment: Have you tried FilteredGroup.GroupBy(x=>x);

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you're on almost there, just check if the name `Contains()` 'Board Testing Admin' or not:

```
List<string> GroupNames = new List<string>();
GroupNames.AddRange(ADConnect.ADConnect.GetGroups(adusername));
var group1 = GroupNames.Where(g => g.Contains("Board Testing Admin"));
var group2 = GroupNames.Where(g => !g.Contains("Board Testing Admin"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> GroupNames = new List<string>();
GroupNames.AddRange(ADConnect.ADConnect.GetGroups(adusername));
List<string> FilteredBoardTestingGroup = new List<string>();
List<string> FilteredBoardAdminGroup = new List<string>();

var FilteredName = new String[] { "Board Testing" };
var names = GroupNames.Where(t => FilteredName.Any(c => t.Contains(c)));
FilteredBoardTestingGroup.AddRange(names);

FilteredName = new String[] { "Board Testing Admin" };
names = GroupNames.Where(t => FilteredName.Any(c => t.Contains(c)));
FilteredBoardAdminGroup.AddRange(names);

cmbgroup1.DataSource = FilteredBoardTestingGroup;
cmbgroup2.DataSource = FilteredBoardAdminGroup;
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this, the 2 examples I gave are not constants.  Tomorrow there could be "Board HaHa" and "Board HaHa Admin" added.  The only non variables will be "Board" in the beginning and "Admin" on the end of some.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this extension method...**

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<List<T>> split<T>(this List<T> source, int sizeOfList) 
    {
        return source
            .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index / sizeOfList)
            .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
List<string> test = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
List<List<string>> temp = test.split(test.Count);
```

Comment: I still haven't been able to get any of this working correctly.  I haven't had to do this to a list before so I'm learning as I go.

Comment: @Jynx Create the ListExtension class in your Project.... Then any of your list property will have the split method.... You just create the ListExtensions method..... then use...
    
var temp = FilteredGroup.split(FilteredGroup.length);

the temp variable will have the seperated lists that you want...